# Push object properties in an array into another array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to figure out how to take objects from one array and merge them into objects of another array of objects. I'm using **Typescript** in an **angular 5** application.

**Array 1:**

```
[
  {
    "outcomeId": 1,
    "outcomeName": "draw",
    "stake": 100
  },
  {
    "outcomeId": 12,
    "outcomeName": "Gandzasar Kapan FC 2",
    "stake": 100000000
  }
]
```

**Array 2:**

```
[
  {
    "success": true
  },
  {
    "success": false,
    "error": {
        "description": "Insufficient balance 989066"
       }
    }
 ]
```

**Result array:**

```
[
  {
    "outcomeId": 9171077,
    "outcomeName": "draw",
    "stake": 100,
    "success": true
  },
  {
    "outcomeId": 9171076,
    "outcomeName": "Gandzasar Kapan FC 2",
    "stake": 100000000,
    "success": false,
    "error": {
      "description": "Insufficient balance 989066"
    }
  }
]
```

I know how to use **.map** to loop over an array, but I have no idea how to do it with two and then merge them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This approach will create a new array and some objects will be referenced by the new array and the older one.

```js
var array1 = [{    "outcomeId": 1,    "outcomeName": "draw",    "stake": 100  },  {    "outcomeId": 12,    "outcomeName": "Gandzasar Kapan FC 2",    "stake": 100000000  }];
var array2 = [{    "success": true  },  {    "success": false,    "error": {      "description": "Insufficient balance 989066"    }  }]

var result = array1.map((o, i) => ({...o, ...array2[i]}))
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Without Spread syntax, using the function `Object.assign`

```js
var array1 = [{    "outcomeId": 1,    "outcomeName": "draw",    "stake": 100  },  {    "outcomeId": 12,    "outcomeName": "Gandzasar Kapan FC 2",    "stake": 100000000  }];
var array2 = [{    "success": true  },  {    "success": false,    "error": {      "description": "Insufficient balance 989066"    }  }]

var result = array1.map((o, i) => Object.assign(o, array2[i]));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer and showing the object.assign option. I used the spread operator option. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
array1.map((element, index) => ({ ...element, ...array2[index]}));
```

This creates new objects by spreading the properties of the current element and those of the respective element at that index in the other array.

```js
const array1 = [
  {
    "outcomeId": 1,
    "outcomeName": "draw",
    "stake": 100
  },
  {
    "outcomeId": 12,
    "outcomeName": "Gandzasar Kapan FC 2",
    "stake": 100000000
  }
]
const array2 =
[
  {
    "success": true
  },
  {
    "success": false,
    "error": {
        "description": "Insufficient balance 989066"
       }
    }
 ]
 
 const result = array1.map((element, index) => ({ ...element, ...array2[index]}));
 
 console.log(result);
```